# stored procedure parameter error c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am creating a website in which i need to call a stored procedure but the following error message is showing

> Procedure expects parameter which was not supplied

My C# code:

```
SqlCommand md = new SqlCommand("SPSelcsclass");  // select charge,shortclass from class where class=@class  
md.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
md.Connection = con;

SqlParameter paam;
paam = new SqlParameter("@class", "SLEEPER CLASS");
paam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
paam.DbType = DbType.String;
cmd.Parameters.Add(paam);

con.Open();

SqlDataReader sdr = md.ExecuteReader();

while (sdr.Read())
{
    lb11.Text = sdr["charge"].ToString();
    lb2.Text = sdr["shortclass"].ToString();
}
```

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
create procedure SPSelcsclass  
    @class nvarchar(500)  
as  
begin  
    select charge, shortclass 
    from class 
    where class = @class  
end
```

Error:

> Procedure or function 'SPSelcsclass' expects parameter '@class', which was not supplied.

Comment: you used `cmd` insted of `md` in this line - `cmd.Parameters.Add(paam);` Replace to `md.Parameters.Add(paam);` will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your offending line (marked up with ** below). It seems you have two commands and you are setting the parameter to command cmd, not md. Replace `cmd.Parameters.Add(paam);` with `md.Parameters.Add(paam);`

```
SqlCommand md = new SqlCommand("SPSelcsclass");//select charge,shortclass from class where class=@class  
                md.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                md.Connection = con;
                SqlParameter paam;
                paam = new SqlParameter("@class", "SLEEPER CLASS");
                paam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                paam.DbType = DbType.String;
                **cmd.Parameters.Add(paam);**
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader sdr = md.ExecuteReader();
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    lb11.Text = sdr["charge"].ToString();
                    lb2.Text = sdr["shortclass"].ToString();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You create two different `SqlCommand` objects in your code and you only need one. That results in you adding parameters to a different command than the one you are calling.

You are calling `SqlCommand cmd` yet you are adding parameters to an `SqlCommand md` which we dont even know where it comes from.

The way you create the parameter is quiet strange to me. I believe you could omit quiet a lot of it and simplyfy all of the code to this:

```
            using (SqlConnection connection = con)
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SPSelcsclass", connection);  // select charge,shortclass from class where class=@class  
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("class", "SLEEPER CLASS");

            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader();
            while(sdr.Read())
            {
                lb11.Text = sdr["charge"].ToString();
                lb2.Text = sdr["shortclass"].ToString();
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
```